# How to filter files in directory in linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, directory

How to display the types of all the files in the personal directory in home directory
that:

1. do not start with certain letters like `a`, `k`
2. and the third letter in their name is not a digit and not a letter 
   (upper or lower case)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

Try grep with regular expressions:

```
ls -1 | grep -ve "^a\|^k\|^..[0-9]\|^..\w" | cut -d . -f 2
```

`-v`: veto matches
`-e`: use regular expressions

The `-1` is to make sure that you don't have several files in one line.

The regular expression means:

1. `^a\|^k`: no `a` or `k` at the beginning
2. `^..[0-9]`: no number at the third position (`.` is a wildcard for one position)
3. `^..\w`: no word (character or `_`) at the third position.

It's a bit longer but I'd consider it as a goog way to dive into regular expressions. For more details about regular expressions look for example [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

The `cut` command looks for the delimiter `.` and prints the second part of it (`-f 2`).

Comment: "The second part" may not be the extension the OP is after. `Filenames.can.have.a.lot.of.dots.in.them.txt`

Comment: @mvds: In that case `sed` would be a better solution.. like for example you did ;)

Answer (score 1):

If by "types" you mean extensions:

```
$ ls | egrep '^[^ak].[^a-zA-Z0-9]' | sed -e s/.*\\.//
```

There are shorthands for `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` but this one is easy to understand and adapt.